# Python Choice for Message Bus Between Objects

Tags: python, message-bus

I need a message bus framework that would allow two Python objects to communicate. What are some of the existing frameworks I could use? I think DBus is overkill at this point (having to involve an external daemon).

Comment: What do you mean with two _objects_ communicating exactly?

Comment: Generic messages back and forth. Standard one object emits and (potentially) multiple objects "connected" will get their callbacks called. I'm using gstreamer and glib/gobjects. With gstreamer, there's a bus being used to communicate between apps and elements. It would be nice to reuse code rather than creating my own bus messaging framework

Comment: Have you looked at [0MQ](http://www.zeromq.org/)?  While it primarily targets network messaging it also has support for in-process communication.  It supports various messaging models, including pub/sub. Also [this](http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/) is a fascinating read.

Answer (score 2):

I ended up using [PyBus](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PyBus/0.1dev-r920). It's a simple messaging bus implemented in about 20 lines of code. It hasn't been updated in a while (and the project site, www.pybus.org, no longer exists), but it does what it needs to do and there aren't any bugs.